# Android App Font Awesome

Tags: java, android

I am creating a sample project with fontawesome, I can't seems to resolve the error. I am following this [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-fontawesome-in-an-android-app--cms-24167). The error is telling me that I can't use the view in the Manager.
The error is:

```
'markAsIconContainer(android.view.View, android.graphics.Typeface)' in 'com.example.fadil.fontawesome.FontManager' cannot be applied to '(android.view.View)'
```

Here is the Codes:

MainActivity:

```
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Typeface iconFont = FontManager.getTypeface(getApplicationContext(), FontManager.FONTAWESOME);
        FontManager.markAsIconContainer(findViewById(R.id.icons_container), iconFont);
    }
}
```

FontManager:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FontManager {

    public static final String ROOT = "fonts/",
            FONTAWESOME = ROOT + "fontawesome-webfont.ttf";

    public static Typeface getTypeface(Context context, String font) {
        return Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), font);
    }

    public static void markAsIconContainer(View v, Typeface typeface) {
        if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;
            for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = vg.getChildAt(i);
                markAsIconContainer(child);
            }
        } else if (v instanceof TextView) {
            ((TextView) v).setTypeface(typeface);
        }
    }

}
```

activity_main layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/icons_container"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="@string/fa_icon_areachart" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="@string/fa_icon_piechart" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="@string/fa_icon_linechart" />
</LinearLayout>
```

LogCat:

```
10-13 12:31:19.155 20432-20432/com.example.fadil.fontawesome E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-13 12:31:19.155 20432-20432/com.example.fadil.fontawesome E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.fadil.fontawesome, PID: 20432
10-13 12:31:19.155 20432-20432/com.example.fadil.fontawesome E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fadil.fontawesome/com.example.fadil.fontawesome.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
10-13 12:31:19.155 20432-20432/com.example.fadil.fontawesome E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2200)
10-13 12:31:19.155 20432-20432/com.example.fadil.fontawesome E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
10-13 12:31:19.155 20432-20432/com.example.fadil.fontawesome E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-13 12:31:19.155 20432-20432/com.example.fadil.fontawesome E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
10-13 12:31:19.155 20432-20432/com.example.fadil.fontawesome E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-13 12:31:19.155 20432-20432/com.example.fadil.fontawesome E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-13 12:31:19.155 20432-20432/com.example.fadil.fontawesome E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113)
10-13 12:31:19.155 20432-20432/com.example.fadil.fontawesome E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-13 12:31:19.155 20432-20432/com.example.fadil.fontawesome E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-13 12:31:19.155 20432-20432/com.example.fadil.fontawesome E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-13 12:31:19.155 20432-20432/com.example.fadil.fontawesome E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
10-13 12:31:19.155 20432-20432/com.example.fadil.fontawesome E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-13 12:31:19.155 20432-20432/com.example.fadil.fontawesome E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
10-13 12:31:19.155 20432-20432/com.example.fadil.fontawesome E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.Typeface.<init>(Typeface.java:175)
10-13 12:31:19.155 20432-20432/com.example.fadil.fontawesome E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:149)
10-13 12:31:19.155 20432-20432/com.example.fadil.fontawesome E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.fadil.fontawesome.FontManager.getTypeface(FontManager.java:18)
10-13 12:31:19.155 20432-20432/com.example.fadil.fontawesome E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.fadil.fontawesome.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
10-13 12:31:19.155 20432-20432/com.example.fadil.fontawesome E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
10-13 12:31:19.155 20432-20432/com.example.fadil.fontawesome E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-13 12:31:19.155 20432-20432/com.example.fadil.fontawesome E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
10-13 12:31:19.155 20432-20432/com.example.fadil.fontawesome E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249) 
10-13 12:31:19.155 20432-20432/com.example.fadil.fontawesome E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141) 
10-13 12:31:19.155 20432-20432/com.example.fadil.fontawesome E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212) 
10-13 12:31:19.155 20432-20432/com.example.fadil.fontawesome E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
10-13 12:31:19.155 20432-20432/com.example.fadil.fontawesome E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
10-13 12:31:19.155 20432-20432/com.example.fadil.fontawesome E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113) 
10-13 12:31:19.155 20432-20432/com.example.fadil.fontawesome E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
10-13 12:31:19.155 20432-20432/com.example.fadil.fontawesome E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
10-13 12:31:19.155 20432-20432/com.example.fadil.fontawesome E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
10-13 12:31:19.155 20432-20432/com.example.fadil.fontawesome E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609) 
10-13 12:31:19.155 20432-20432/com.example.fadil.fontawesome E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Need Help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the answer...

I had to change the ttf file location to the main directory instead of src, and for the markAsIconContainer I add the typeface into the brackets.

Here is the fixed code:

```
    public static void markAsIconContainer(View v, Typeface typeface) {
        if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;
            for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = vg.getChildAt(i);
                markAsIconContainer(child, typeface);
            }
        } else if (v instanceof TextView) {
            ((TextView) v).setTypeface(typeface);
        }
    }

}
```

:)